# How to retrieve ejs data sent from node server in an angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

What is the best practice to retrieve ejs data that is sent from a res.render call from a node server?

here is an example route from my server:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {message: "hello"});
}
```

Do I need to instantiate the variable message in my ejs template? or is there a way to retrieve the "message" field purely through the angular controller?
Thanks.

I've searched for the solution on a similar question on SO but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "res.render" doesn't pass any data to the client. It takes the data you pass it, puts it into the EJS template, renders it, and sends that to the client. For this reason, I'm pretty sure its impossible to retrieve this information through EJS. If you're looking to use AngularJS to data bind this info to the page, a better alternative may be to set up a RESTful API service on the server that can return this information. Angular can then use AJAX to retrieve this information, and bind it to the page.

Comment: i see thanks. Looks like I was confused on how this template engine worked